# ease-in with jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Simple question, but I can't find a way to do it. I have a jQuery animation that scrolls the page to an element:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top},1000);
```

I want the animation to have a slow start and a fast end (ease-in in css). It should work like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#maine").offset().top},1000, "ease-in");
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could do it in two animation steps if you do not want to use jquery ui. Essentially a .animate({scrollTop: ($maine.top - current) * .1 + current},500).animate({original}, 200)

Comment: Aduss's answer is correct, and the only way of doing it without using an external library like animate.css

Answer (score 0):

There are only two easing functions available in plain jQuery: *linear* and *swing*.

Click the black box to see how it works with swing: https://jsfiddle.net/o95dq69m/

```
$(this).animate({'top': topVal}, 500, 'swing', function(){});
```

If you are not afraid of using extra libraries, go ahead and try **jQuery-UI**, there is a ton of easing functions available there, like **easeInExp**:
https://jsfiddle.net/o95dq69m/1/

```
$(this).animate({'top': topVal}, 500, 'easeInExpo', function(){});
```